# How would I use a while loop to get multiple inputs?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'd like to make a program that asks the user to enter the number of customers for booking tickets, reads the entered number, performs the loop to ask the age of each customer, and decide the unit price for each customer.
my code so far only has the if else statements:

```
if (customerP <4){
    System.out.println("The unit Price of customer 1 is: 0");
}else {
    if(customerP <13) {
        System.out.println("The unit price of customer 1 is: 5");
    }else {
        if(customerP <19) {
            System.out.println("The unit price of customer 1 is: 8");
        }else {
            System.out.println("The unit price of customer 1 is: 10");
        }
    }    
}
```

How do I add a while loop to ask the to ask the age for each customer?

Comment: Look about `else if` in one command, to avoid to imbricate if like here

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter No of Customers: ");
int noCustomers = scanner.nextInt();

if (noCustomers < 1) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("No of Customers has to be 1 or greater");
}

int[] customerAges = new int[noCustomers];

for (int i = 0; i < noCustomers; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter age for customer: " + i);
    customerAges[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Ages: " + Arrays.toString(customerAges));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Below provides code using while loop*

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int customerCount = sc.nextInt();

int[] ageOfCustomers = new int[customerCount];
int i=0;
while(customerCount-- > 0) {

    ageOfCustomers[i++] = sc.nextInt();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ageOfCustomers));
```